# How to Pass data with Notification to Main Activity

Tags: android, cordova, android-notifications

Am using phonegap 2.5.0 for my android app. In this am enabling notification with intent. The intent having some extra data. The notification code is below,

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, contentTitle, when);
// Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationType", "updateAvailable");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("updateUrl", updateUrl);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("updateVersion", updateVersion);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, notificationIntent, 0);
    //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1, notification);
```

The above generated notification calling the mainactivity of the android app. The MainActivity script is below,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String notificationType = intent.getStringExtra("notificationType");

    if(extras != null)
    {
        if(extras.getString("notificationType").equals("updateAvailable"))
        {
            String updateUrl = extras.getString("updateUrl");
            String updateVersion = extras.getString("updateVersion");
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/update.html?updateVersion="+updateVersion+"&updateUrl="+updateUrl);
        }else
            startMyApp();
    }else
    {
        startMyApp();
    }           
}
```

The startMyApp function having code to start application (only called while opening the application directly using application icon).

But the code not working. Application not working (i.e application not opened on clicking the application icon) Unfortunately stopped Application error displayed and application was closed. If am removing intent receiving contents from oncreate function and if only the startMyApp() function called from onCreate application started successfully.

Help me to pass data with notification to MainActivity. The startMyApp()'s code is below

```
public void startMyApp()
{
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/dashboard.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/update.html?updateVersion="+updateVersion+"&updateUrl="+updateUrl);
```

This will not work, since it will search for a file named update.html?updateVersion=xxx&updateUrl=xxx and not update.html.

Comment: While am opening that application from application icon the intent not triggered or started, normal open only take place. But in that time also application not working.

Comment: The logcat error data:
04-04 17:14:28.976: E/AndroidRuntime(591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myPackage/mypackage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Else can you provide me a good example to generate notification with hidden data, onclicking the notification hidden data should be passed to MainActivity.